# Dynamics CRM Business Rule And or conditions

Tags: dynamics-crm-online

Below question is a dump CRM exam question. I have reproduced the question on CRM online and it seems that the answer should be 3. But according to dump paper it is 2.

Here is the question:

> You are creating a business rule for the account records. The business
>   rule will perform an action if the record has Country set to the
>   United States and City set to either Redmond or San Francisco. You
>   need to identify the minimum number of condition sets required to
>   implement this logic. What should you identify?
>
> A. 1
>   B. 2
>   C. 3
>   D. 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting confused between Advanced Find and a Business Rule.

In an Advanced Find, you would need 3 conditions:

1. Country = USA; AND
2. State = Redmond; OR
3. State = San Francisco

[image: Adv Find]

However, the question asks about Business Rules, which can combine conditions into groups of `AND` and `OR` so you only need 2:

1. Country = USA; AND
2. State = Redmond OR State = San Francisco

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like 2, one AND and one OR condition (`country AND (city OR city)`)

Answer (score 0):

@JasonScript,

based on your solution, the Business rule is doing if the country is NOT the USA, and the City is Redmond or San Francisco, then Action.

I am facing the same problem if (A and (B or C or D)), and business rules are not great doing this.

the solution is to do if (A and B) then action
else if (A and C) then action
else if (A and D) then action
else if do nothing....

so in the givenexample the answer is two

if (USA and San Francisco) then do action A
else if (USA and Redmond) then do action A
else if do nothing
end if

Cheers